# Form with hashset attribute jsp spring mvc

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I am working with spring mvc and i want to know how get a hashset from a checkbox

Muy problem is that the checkbox return null

Comment: If you post a code snippet you're much more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller class, in any method, you need to populate hashset in Model and use it page.

For e.g.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/member.htm")
public class MemberController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initForm(Model model) {
        Member member = new Member();
        Set<String> data = new HashSet<String>();
        courses.add("Yoga");
        courses.add("Stretching");
        courses.add("Pilates");
        courses.add("Aerobic");
        courses.add("Oriental");
        model.addAttribute("courses", courses);
        return "member";
    }
}
```

Use spring-taglib for use HashSet like:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<title>Spring MVC checkbox</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Subscribe to the gym</h2>

    <form:form method="POST" commandName="member">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Choose the courses you like:</td>
                <td><form:checkboxes path="courses" items="${courses}" /> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```